# Why are all non-singular curves absolutely irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-curves

I was reading Judy Walker's book Codes and Curves, and one of the exercise's in the book (ex. 4.6) was proving that every non-singular curve is abaolutely irreducible.

I'm not so familiar with algebric geometry, and I'm not so sure how to approach this (beside playing a bit with the definitions, which reached a dead end).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a curve $\cal C$ is not absolutely irreducible, it will split as ${\cal C}={\cal C}_1\cup{\cal C}_2$ over some algebraically closed field. Then every point in the non-empty intersection ${\cal C}_1\cap{\cal C}_2$ would be a singular (non-smooth) point of ${\cal C}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why is the intersection non-empty?

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field two projective palne curves always intersect. Check the theory of *resultants* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) or, if you want a big shot, *Bezout's theorem* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem)